# How to get checkbox variables using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a checkbox that when checked the value is retrievable by a $_GET['image_name']. It works in my other php code, but I'm having some trouble with ajax. Must be something simple. It's not "getting" the image_name variables (which is an array).

I am using the following code and the output is simply "image_name is empty".

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $i ?>" class="checkbox" value="some_image.jpg" name="image_name[]"/>

<button type="button" onClick="rename_image()" class="button_class" name="rename" id="rename" value="rename">Rename</button>
```

and the js:

```
function rename_image() 
{
    var button = document.getElementById('options_menu_details');
    {
        var div = document.getElementById('show_options_rename'); // display select_show
        if (div.style.visibility == 'hidden') 
        {
            div.style.visibility = 'visible';
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url:"test4.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {func: 'toptable'},
                    success:function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        else 
        {
            div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

}
```

and the php file test4.php:

```
<?php //test4.php
function toptable()
{
    echo 'toptable';
}

if(empty($_GET['image_name']))
{
    echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is empty</div>';
}
else
{
    foreach($_GET['image_name'] as $rowid_rename)
    {
        echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is NOT empty</div><br>';

    }
}       
echo "test";


?>
```

Does ajax actually GET the image_name[] or is there something I'm missing? What happens is the user checks the checkbox and then clicks the "Rename" button. But the ajax doesn't seem to pick up on the checkbox and I want it to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $.ajax doesn't know anything about elements in the page. You need to tell it what data to send based on those elements. Using `serialize()` can be very helpful http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: How would I go about that? How do I pass the data in ajax e.g. var `pass_data = {'<?php echi $i ?>' : "image_name[]"}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to modify the following line:

```
data: {func: 'toptable'},
```

to this:

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

It seems serialize gathers the `value` information from the form and processes it into a format that PHP can then $_GET e.g. my $*GET*['image_name'] is working now. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What I still don't know is how to indicate which form I want the js to serialize. e.g. `data: $('form_1').serialize(),` ? Does anybody know how to assign the form id?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [jQuery $.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) we can see the `data` tag has everything you want to send with your GET request. The only thing you're sending with your GET request right now is ?func=toptable.

You will want to add the value of your checkbox to that, and i'll work.

For debugging this kind of issue, the developer console is very handy (the network tab in particular)!

Comment: How do I add that to the ajax request? What's the code look like? This is my first ajax program.

Comment: I read that article but it's not easy to understand being the first ajax I've written. There are no examples of how to add a $_GET['image_name'] to the code. Can somebody tell me what code I'm supposed to write to get the value of the checkbox passed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my HTML page, I define a javascript function that takes the base name of the array and deals with it (note that I'm storing these in one field in a DB delimited by colons so I convert them all into one big string to send to the processing PHP script) -

```
function SaveCheckboxes(cbref){

        var myVal="";

        toSave=document.forms['formName'].elements[cbref];
            for(j=0;j<toSave.length;j++){
                if(toSave[j].checked){
                    myVal+=":"+toSave[j].value;
                }
            }
            var pass_data = {
                'radioID' : "gened",
                'radioVal' : myVal,
            };

        $.ajax({
            url : "saveIt.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : pass_data,
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
   return false;
}
```

And when I create the checkboxes in the HTML (well, I read from an array with PHP...) I tell it to call that function onClick -

```
        print("<input onClick=\"SaveCheckboxes('gened[]');\"");
        if(in_array($gened_courses[$i],$geneds)){print(" checked ");}
        print(" type=checkbox name=gened[] value=".$gened_courses[$i]."><font face=\"courier\">".$gened_courses[$i]."</font>: ".ucwords(strtolower($course_names[$gened_courses[$i]]))." <br />\n");
```

Comment: So pass_data = { 'get_image_name' : "$_GET['image_name']"}? Or something like it? Am I supposed to pass the variables of the html and not trying to GET with php?